# Force restarted laptop when uninstalling XAMPP because it froze now the old XAMPP folder is stuck

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, uninstallation

So after my laptop was turned back on, xampp is uninstalled (as it was no longer shown in my Programs and Features) but when I go into my C drive, the xampp folder is still there.

I'm guessing it is because during the uninstall I had to force shut down my laptop since it froze, so it didn't finish uninstalling (remove the files)?

I tried to delete the xampp folder but it will be forever loading and freezes up my laptop so I would have to force shut it down. I tried to go in and delete individual things which worked except from the apache folder.

I tried to delete it by using git bash by doing some rm commands, that didn't do the trick either.

I wanted to install xampp again but couldn't (since old xampp folder was there) so I renamed the old xampp folder to something else "blah". So now I have a xampp folder and a blah folder which is the old xampp folder.

I read on stackoverflow that I need to stop Apache and mySQL in services.msc but I can't see those anywhere when I look into services.msc.

Btw I am using a Windows 8 laptop if that is helpful.

Could anyone give me any guidance on how to delete this old xampp folder?

Thanks!

Comment: open task manager, stop apache/mysql in their. or disable them startting and rebot

Comment: Try [UnLocker](https://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php) Helped me a ton

Answer (score -1):

Go to task manager open
`Details`
Then you will see `apache httpd` right-click, end task or right down is ea button end task. It worked by me.